# Ubuntu 16.04, CUDA 8 - CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I've installed the latest nvidia drivers (375.26) manually, and installed CUDA using cuda_8.0.44_linux.run (skipping the driver install there, since the bundled drivers are older, 367 I think).

Running the deviceQuery in CUDA samples produces the following error however:

```
~/cudasamples/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery$ ./deviceQuery 
./deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 35
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
Result = FAIL
```

Version info:

$ nvcc --version

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Sep__4_22:14:01_CDT_2016
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.44

$ nvidia-smi
Sat Dec 31 17:25:03 2016       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26                 Driver Version: 375.26                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:01:00.0      On |                  N/A |
|  0%   39C    P8    11W / 230W |    464MiB /  8110MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       974    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                             193MiB |
|    0      1816    G   compiz                                         172MiB |
|    0      2178    G   ...ignDownloads/Enabled/MaterialDesignUserMa    96MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$  cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version 
NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  375.26  Thu Dec  8 18:36:43 PST 2016
GCC version:  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
```

The anwer to similar problems has been updating the nvidia display drivers, though in my case this is already done. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You may have some old driver components that were on your machine from a previous install.  You may also have not properly removed the `nouveau` driver.  I'm sure there are other possibilities as well.  The [cuda 8 linux install guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#abstract) covers all the necessary information to get CUDA working on a clean load of the OS.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Running

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
```

and reinstalling the drivers using

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-375`

solved it. Just for the record, the first time I updated the drivers using the GUI (Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates).

Comment: thanks, had exactly the same situation and this worked. Maybe it was because transitional 367 packages.

Comment: one shot and accurate, strange downgrading behaviour

Answer (score 28):

First, check "CUDA Toolkit and Compatible Driver Versions" from [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html), and make sure that your cuda toolkit version is compatible with your cuda-driver version， e.g. if your driver version is `nvidia-390`, your cuda version must lower than `CUDA 9.1`.
Then, back to this issue. This issue is caused by "your cuda-driver version doesn't match your cuda version, and your CUDA local version may also different from the CUDA runtime version(cuda version in some specific virtual environments)."
I met the same issue when I tried to run tensorflow-gpu under the environment of "tensorflow_gpuenv" created by conda, and tried to test whether the "gpu:0" device worked. My driver version is `nvidia-390` and I've already install `cuda 9.0`, so it doesn't make sense that raising that weird issue. I finally found the reason that the cuda version in the conda virtual environment is `cuda 9.2` which isn't compatible with `nvidia-390`. I solved the issue by following steps in `ubuntu 18.04`:

- check **cuda driver version**
  `~$ nvidia-smi` or `~$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version`
- check **local cuda version**
  `~$ nvcc --version` or `~$ cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt`
- check **local cudnn version**
  `~$ cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2`

  ---
- check **cuda version in virtual environment**
  `~$ conda list` you can see something like these :
  cudatoolkit        9.2          0
  cudnn          7.3.1          cuda9.2_0
  you may find that the cuda version in virtual environment is different from the local cuda version, and isn't compatible with driver version `nvidia-390`.

So reinstall cuda in the virtual environment:

- reinstall cuda : `~$ conda install cudatoolkit=8.0`
  (change the version number '8.0' to other version number which match your driver version, and your cudnn version will update automatically to match the new version cuda )

Comment: In cudnn version 8 I had to use `cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn_version.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2 | head -3`

Answer (score 3):

I have followed the instructions on this page, and it works for me.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=debnetwork

First, download installer for Linux Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64.

Next, follow these steps to install Linux Ubuntu:

1. `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.2.148-1_amd64.deb`
2. `sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get install cuda`

Comment: This looked too simple but it certainly worked, after trying all else. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was with the same problem. I had the version nvidia-390 installed on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. My Graphic card is  GeForce GTX 1080, and using tensorflow 1.12.0.
I successfully solved this problem by removing the old version:

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`

And then installing the version 418

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-418 nvidia-settings`

Answer (score 1):

My cent,

the problem may be related to the selected GPU mode (Performance/Power Saving Mode). The Perfomance mode uses the Nvidia GPU, and the Power Saving Mode changes to the Intel Integrated GPU. When you select (using `nvidia-settings` utility, in the "PRIME Profiles" configurations) the Power Saving Mode (integrated Intel GPU) and you execute the `deviceQuery` script... you get this error:

```
-> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

But this error is misleading,
by **selecting** back the **Performance Mode (NVIDIA GPU)** with **nvidia-settings** utility the  problem disappears.

In my case **I had not a driver version problem** but I simply need to re-enable the Nvidia GPU.

Regards

P.s: The selection is available when Prime-related-stuff is installed (you need the Nvidia proprietary driver). Further details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/858030/nvidia-prime-in-nvidia-x-server-settings-in-16-04-1

Comment: How do I access "NVIDIA(Performance mode)" setting? When I run nvidia-settings, I don't see this option

Comment: When in power saving mode I have three pages from nvidia-settings menu: PRIME Profiles, Application Profiles, nvidia-settings-conf; PRIME Profiles brings you to the selection switch. I'm working with Mint and I installed the proprietary driver manually. I don't know if PRIME is supported by all the mobo around, perhaps you have to install Prime-related-stuff too. here you find screenshots and few instructions about: https://askubuntu.com/questions/858030/nvidia-prime-in-nvidia-x-server-settings-in-16-04-1

Comment: I updated my answer, I have forgotten that Prime was not a default feature.

Comment: Another related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/805199/prime-profiles-tab-missing-in-nvidia-x-server-settings-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I have received some downvotes. Is there anything I'm overlooking here which I could address?

Answer (score 1):

I got that error on Ubuntu 16.04, because I was still using the open-source X.Org video driver. The error went away when I switched to the NVIDIA binary driver.

I found the driver settings by opening the System Settings, then clicking on Software & Updates. The video drivers are on the Additional Drivers tab.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the answer of #Fabiano-Tarlao, if you already have installed the required NVidia driver, you can select it from the Linux command-line using:

sudo prime-select nvidia

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.I am using anaconda, after installing keras-gpu through conda, it automatically took the most recent version of cuda, which was not compatible with my system.

You can view list of installed packages in anaconda through

```
conda list
```

In my case supported version was 10.0 but anaconda installed the latest version 10.1.
if this is the case, you need to reinstall cuda in anaconda enviournment with supported version.

Answer (score 0):

During my experiments(Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - on Thinkpad 470s - NVIDIA GeForce 940MX), what I learned is that Table 2. CUDA Toolkit and Compatible Driver Versions from this release notes section of the website (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html) is the most important information that you need to keep in mind while installing CUDA drivers.

Also, you can compare whether your NVIDIA Driver version and the table is in Sync by checking with the command

`$nvidia-smi`

The output will look something like this for the latest

> NVIDIA-SMI 450.66       Driver Version: 450.66       CUDA Version: 11.0

[image]

[image]

Once everything is in place, you can get it working by copying the samples and run them as follows,

```
$ cp -r /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v8/ .
$ cd cudnn_samples_v8/
$ cd mnistCUDNN/
$ make clean && make
$ ./mnistCUDNN
```

You'll get the results as ...

> Executing: mnistCUDNN
> cudnnGetVersion() : 8003 , CUDNN_VERSION from cudnn.h : 8003 (8.0.3)
> Host compiler version : GCC 9.3.0

> There are 1 CUDA capable devices on your machine :
> device 0 : sms  3  Capabilities 5.0, SmClock 1189.0 Mhz, MemSize (Mb) 2004, MemClock 2505.0 Mhz, Ecc=0, boardGroupID=0
> Using device 0
> ..........

> Resulting weights from Softmax:
> 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000714 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
> Loading image data/five_28x28.pgm
> Performing forward propagation ...
> Resulting weights from Softmax:
> 0.0000000 0.0000008 0.0000000 0.0000002 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000154 0.0000000 0.0000012 0.0000006

> Result of classification: 1 3 5

> Test passed!

I had to try at least 5-6 times before I realized the correlation between NVIDIA drivers and CUDA versions and then it all worked in the next attempt. But a very happy ending nonetheless to get it working.