# OpenCL doesn't display Nvidia GPU

Tags: linux, anaconda, opencl, nvidia, pyopencl

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate, I did have a look around but correct me if I'm wrong.

I recently installed `pyopencl` via Anaconda and it runs on my Intel CPU without a problem. However, when I call:

```
for platform in get_platforms():
    print(platform.name)

ctx = create_some_context()

for dev in ctx.devices:
    print(dev.name)
```

All I get back is:

```
Portable Computing Language
Choose platform:
[0] <pyopencl.Platform 'Portable Computing Language' at 0x7f0ff2205020>
>> 0
Choice [0]:0
Set the environment variable PYOPENCL_CTX='0' to avoid being asked again.
pthread-Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
```

I have the Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, and the driver version is 390.87 with CUDA 9.1, which should be compatible according to the Nvidia release notes. I'm also running Linux Mint 19.1 (if that's relevant), and am also a bit of a noob when it comes to this stuff as my background is in Physics, not computer science.

I read somewhere (I can't remember where) that I should have an nvidia.icd file but all that's present is a pocl.icd file in /home//anaconda3/etc/OpenCL/vendors and I'm not sure how/where to get an nvidia.icd file.

Thanks in advance for any help, and let me know if you need anymore info!

Edit: added the result of `get_platforms()`

**Edit 2: I was able to find an `nvidia.icd` file in my `/etc/OpenCL/vendors` directory. I copied this over to the Anaconda directory, `/home/<user>/anaconda3/etc/OpenCL/vendors` and `pyopencl` now recognises `Nvidia CUDA` as a platform, and my GPU as a device.**

Unfortunately it's still loading the tasks off to the CPU, but there's a good chance that's because of my code and I haven't properly figured out how to create context on the GPU yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit stale, but I ran across it while trying to solve exactly this problem, I had a freshly-installed PyOpenCL package inside a Conda environment on Ubuntu Linux, and it was not listing my GPU in the list of platforms and their associated devices.

The 2nd edit by the OP, where he copied over the nvidia.icd file from `/etc/OpenCL/vendors` worked for me, but it didn't feel right, so I dug a bit deeper into the PyOpenCL [documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/misc.html), which recommends, in addition to the PyOpenCL package, doing `conda install ocl-icd-system`. (See the section on "Using vendor-supplied drivers" on that page.)

This works, and gets you all of the system capabilities -- I think it's a cleaner approach than copying `.icd` files around.

Comment: This is the correct answer, spent 6 hours debugging my system trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

Your system has multiple OpenCL platforms and devices, and `create_some_context` will just choose one. If you want to use a specific device, you need to enumerate the platforms and devices available using `get_platforms()` and `Platform.get_devices()`.

Comment: Sorry I should have added this, but when I call a loop over platform.name I get just one platform: `Portable Computing Language`.

Which I presume is the `pocl` platform.

Comment: @WilfridSomogyi could you double check with `clinfo` (you may need to install the program with your system's package manager) and maybe try updating your graphics card drivers?

Comment: Ok, so running that it looks like `NVIDIA CUDA` is available as a platform and my graphics card is listed as an available device. Which all looks good, but then at the end there's a load of info under `NULL platform behavior` that I can't decipher.

Comment: @WilfridSomogyi The `NULL platform behavior` section shows what happens when certain OpenCL functions are called with `NULL` - for example, calling `clGetDeviceIDs` but passing `NULL` for the platf orm ID may use a "default" platform. You can pretty much ignore this, it shouldn't change what happens when you iterate the platforms/devices manually.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps my suggestion applies only to laptop PCs (Intel CPU+Nvidia GPU+Linux) and it is not your case. I had this problem while using tensoflow time ago.

When the Nvidia card does not appear in the available devices (@apemanzilla answer), let's check if you have enabled the *Performance Mode* in the `nvidia-settings` *Primes Profiles*.
Conversely *Power Saving Mode* only enables the integrated Intel GPU.

Further details about "Prime stuff" :-) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41409842/ubuntu-16-04-cuda-8-cuda-driver-version-is-insufficient-for-cuda-runtime-vers/49156089#49156089)

Comment: My Nvidia card is definitely running. I have 'Performance Mode' selected in the Prime settings, and calling `sudo prime-select nvidia` tells me `the nvidia profile is already set`.

Comment: I'm sorry, your problem seems related to pyopencl, which I never used.

Answer (score 1):

try:

sudo apt install nvidia-opencl-icd

if there is no <pyopencl.Platform 'NVIDIA CUDA' at 0x559e3a192fb0>.