# tensor flow is not working in anaconda gettting CUDA runtime version error on window system

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow library was working on my system, I have installed other library now tensorflow is not working. I am using window 10. python 3.7, tensorflow 1.13.1.
I am getting following error:

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Yogesh/.spyder-py3/MNISTBasicClassification.py', wdir='C:/Users/Yogesh/.spyder-py3')

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Yogesh/.spyder-py3/MNISTBasicClassification.py", line 58, in 
    model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 880, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 251, in model_iteration
    model.reset_metrics()

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1119, in reset_metrics
    m.reset_states()

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py", line 460, in reset_states
    K.set_value(v, 0)

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 2847, in set_value
    get_session().run(assign_op, feed_dict={assign_placeholder: value})

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 479, in get_session
    session = _get_session()

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py", line 457, in _get_session
    config=get_default_session_config())

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1551, in **init**
    super(Session, self).**init**(target, graph, config=config)

File "C:\Users\Yogesh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 676, in **init**
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)

InternalError: cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

Comment: Maybe this answer will provide some help.https://stackoverflow.com/a/55351774/7121726

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post the pip list showing versions of packages, and specifically if you installed the cuda package within conda (conda list shows this)

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the tensorflow and then created a new environment and then reinstalled the tensorflow then the issue was resolved.